# How to implement unit test on a web page?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a registration page and i want to test the page as a developer,but i dont know how to do it?I am not that much into testing side so how can i test the page and i heard that unit testing will do the job but how to implement it?

Comment: You can automate tests like that, but they don't fall under unit testing and use different tools than unit tests. What you *can* unit test is every single component involved under the hood, but you do that in isolation.

Comment: Unit testing is what developers do ! If there is a testing team they will do end to end testing. You can do some basic testing according for the module you have developed without integrating with other developed codes

Comment: What kind of basic tests i can do as a developer?do i have to use any third party tools or i can test in the visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

This subject is vast. What I can say is that unit tests are not suitable for user interface tests. For that you need other tools and in general these tests are done by other team members who are not developers (and it is preferable that it be so, developers are too lazy to explore the weaknesses of the UI).

These links can show you what is and what is not UI and Unit tests from the perspective of a tool:

Unit tests on VS2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx
UI Tests on VS2012 Ultimate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx

Comment: So for this can i use third party tools??

Comment: Yes, there 3rd party tools in the market. Resharper can run the same unit tests develop for VS and NUnit is a free open source unit tests framework. On the UI test I do not have much to say because it is not my area, but must have other tools out there too ...